# Get Identifier using ID in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm developing an android app in which when user clicks on a text view a listener is triggered. I can obtain the **ID** from the **View.getId();** method. But is there is any way i can obtain its Unique Identifier String that i mentioned in XML file ?
Like

```
public void onClickTV(View v)
    {
        int ID = v.getId();
    }

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/myTextView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Click Here"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:onClick="onClickTV" 
 android:clickable="true" />
```

It gives me only ID which is integer, can i get the identifier through any method which is "myTextView"

Comment: Instead of making a clickable textview, you should use a button with a transparent background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public void onClickTV(View v)
{
    int ID = v.getId();
    String myResourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(ID);
}
```

That returns the the value you're looking for.

See the [Resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) for other methods of reading resource properties.

Comment: In case you didn't notice I just barely made an edit. `getResourceEntryName` will return just the entry name of the element, which is what you'd asked for in your question, rather than the full resource name with package and type which is what I'd initially shown.